# OCX error "Component not correctly registered"

Tags: vb6

I am facing an issue when trying to place an OCX on Win form in VB6. The Active X control project got successfully built and i have registered it manually too. It got registered properly too. I am using Win10 OS machine.

On placing it is throwing "Component not correctly registered".

I have checked the registry and the entry is proper. (I compared with the one that is working on Win 7 OS machine).

I ran out of ideas.. Please suggest..

Comment: Is this a VB6 application or is it a VBA scenario, like using the control on a form in Excel?

Comment: This is VB6 application.

Comment: It is possible the OCX is missing dependencies (ie ,other DLLs)

Comment: What the above person said is very likely, I've used this Dependency Walker tool before and it's saved me so much time - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-walker

Comment: Might very well be the case. An equally irritating message is also thrown by Windows calling/loading a native Win32 DLL and it's missing a dependency. _"Can't load <path>\<file>.dll"_, although the DLL is right there

Comment: Ya, the issue,  is i was having an older version of one dependent dll. Got the newer version and registering it. Then the ocx was getting placed on the form properly.

Comment: Thanks All for the suggestions.

Comment: When you said you registered the component, do you mean  you did ran `regsvr32`?  If so, are you sure that you have the license on your Windows 10 machine for the OCX to be used in a designer? Some author's of ActiveX components made two versions, one that can be used only for runtime another for runtime and design time.  I have a feeling that you registered the OCX which is meant for runtime only.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the OCX is missing dependencies (ie ,other DLLs) .

This was later confirmed by the OP:

> Ya, the issue, is i was having an older version of one dependent dll.
> Got the newer version and registering it. Then the ocx was getting
> placed on the form properly. –  Latha  May 15, 2020 at 13:53